# Displaying Prime Number Through Looping

Tags: java, loops

In the following loop :

```
while (j <= number / 2)
```

What is the need for the number to be divided by 2?
Does it affect the running time to build the program or something?

Comment: It's just saying that while j is less than or equal to have the number...

Answer (score 1):

If this condition is taken from a method that tests if `number` is prime, it should only test if it's divisable by numbers `j` such that `j <= Math.sqrt(number)`, so `j <= number/2` is an overkill. Still, it gives better performance than testing for all `j <= number`.

Comment: I would say it's an underkill

Comment: @Bohemian Is it? If you are doing more work than you should, isn't it considered overkill?

Comment: You are doing more work than you should, because the exit condition test is _under_whelming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it cuts the runtime by half (*).

You don't need to check numbers bigger than half your number. They won't be factors.

This is a very loose upper bound, though. You can stop much earlier (at the square root: there will be factors bigger than the square root, but you will have found those already via the other factor of the pair).

(*) if you compute `number/2` just once on top of the loop, that is. If you compute it repeatedly in every iteration, you waste quite a bit of those savings again.

Comment: "waste quite a bit": Division by 2 is faster than other divisions, though. But still...